# Is Heritage Druid's ability limited by summoning sickness?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-manabase

[Heritage Druid](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bHeritage%20Druid%5d)'s ability is:

> Tap three untapped elves, add {G}{G}{G} to your mana pool

Once I play Heritage Druid, can I tap three elves (Heritage Druid being one of them) and get {G}{G}{G} to my mana pool?

Just trying to be specific here, thought that several players might have the same problems and could solve it with this thread. But still, thank you all for reading and trying to answer this problem for me.

Comment: I don't see how it's relevant to the question, but no, you can't Stifle that ability. It's a mana ability.

Comment: I looked at that question and I don't see where in the answer it talks about using abilities that do not have a tap symbol as part of the cost even though it was mentioned in the question.

Comment: I disagree with the duplicate, while the question is about summoning sickness certainly, the specifics of an ability that involve tapping creatures (potentially even this creature) but don't use the tap symbol as part of a cost are not covered in the duplicate question. We should never use the assumption that an answer is comprehensive and covers all cases, so the fact it doesn't say you can't do this means you can. Particularly with how much magic's rules have changed.

Comment: @Andrew From the duplicate's answer, under "How are the creatures affected?": *Summoning sickness does not prevent you from paying other costs, even if they involve tapping the creature.*

Comment: I added some examples to my answer in the linked question, including one that specifically addresses Heritage Druid.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to gatherer it is not impacted by summoning sickness since it doesn't have the tap symbol.

> Since [Heritage Druid](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bHeritage%20Druid%5d)’s activated ability doesn’t have a tap symbol in its cost, you can tap creatures that haven’t been under your control since your most recent turn began (including Heritage Druid itself) to pay the cost.